# How to handle a POSTed JS array in Pyramid

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, pyramid

I have an AJAX request:

```
var groupName = $('#group-input').val();
var cidArray = [];

$("#sortWrapper .contact-wrapper").children('.is-checked').each(function() {
        cidArray.push($(this).attr('cid'));
});

$.ajax({     
    type: "POST",
    url: "/ajax/create/",
    data: {group_name: groupName, group_user_id: cidArray},
    cache: false,
    success: function(result) {
        alert(groupName); // These both alert the proper values
        alert(cidArray);
    }
});
```

Which posts data to my handler in Pyramid. The relevant parts are:

```
group_name = request.POST.get('group_name', None)
group_user_id = request.POST.getall('group_user_id')

for index,uid in enumerate(group_user_id):
    # perform actions on each user...
    print uid
```

I receive `group_name` as expected; however, I am having trouble also then receiving the values posted from the JS array `cidArray`. The array is populated as expected, but the problem occurs when I need to then retrieve those values using the key of `group_user_id`.

All I can seem to get with the above is an empty list `[]` or when using a different syntax:

```
request.POST.get('group_user_id', [])
```

it defaults to that empty list.

Note: Needless to say, the preceding `for uid in...` hasn't yet been tested or refined, but if possible, I would like the end result of my `group_user_id` to be a list of those values originally present in `cidArray`.

Help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: what content-type is the data? POST only works with form-encoded data, not json

Comment: Each value added to the cidArray is a number. My goal is to pass this array – a certain amount of number values – to my python code so that each can be used in future operations and such. I was under the impression that this was the proper syntax for posting data. As seen above, I also have a String called groupName (which is successfully captured in the Python code, so-to-speak.) Does that help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, after mindless toiling and suffering, I have discovered how to fix this:

Instead of

```
request.POST.getall('group_user_id') # This is wrong
```

I needed:

```
request.POST.getall('group_user_id[]') # This works
```

The `getall` retrieves all the values present under the one key, and the `[]` deal with the fact that it's an array. Everything else remained the same.

Hope this helps someone at some point.

Comment: So, if I may offer a tip. if you want to see how data is being received by your web app, look at the request in the network tab of your favorite browser OR, you can always log the requeest. str(request) will give you the entire http msg in all it's glory.

Comment: That's actually what I ended up doing to find this answer as far as looking in the network tab (albeit after far too much time  was wasted.) But I was unaware of the str(request). I'll definitely make use of that in the future. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: yeah obviously dont do that in production, but it is handy when you need it :)

Answer (score 0):

will [this](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.5-branch/narr/webob.html#request-json-body) help? it uses **req.json_body**